# What is a regex to extract words and punctuation but ignore decimals and numbers?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following sentence:

```
"We bought 3.5 million shirts."
```

I want to create an array with all of the words and punctuation but not the number including the decimal point.

I have the following regex:

```
/[\D]+/
```

However this still grabs the decimal point between the numbers as follows:

["We", "bought", ".", "million", "shirts", "."]

I want the result to be as follows: looking for the following result:

```
["We", "bought", "million", "shirts", "."]
```

Notice that the "." from the number is excluded.

How can I still select periods at the end of sentences but not decimal points that occur before a number?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "words"? Share the expected output, please. BTW, `\D+` matches what `[[:punct:]]+` matches, no need to use `|[[:punct:]]+` in your pattern.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, for me `str.scan(/[\D]+/) # => ["We bought ", ".", " million shirts."]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a small enhancement: replace `\D+` with `\p{L}+` (or `[[:alpha:]]+`) to only match 1+ letters and then restrict `[[:punct:]]` to only match if it is not a `.` followed with a digit (with a negative lookahead `(?!\.\d)`):

```
s = "We bought 3.5 million shirts."
res = s.scan(/\p{L}+|(?!\.\d)[[:punct:]]/)
puts res # => [We, bought, million, shirts, .]
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/j8W3gX)

Another approach is to first remove all numbers with `\d*\.?\d+` regex and then collect the "words" with punctuation:

```
s = "We bought 3.5 million shirts."
res = s.gsub(/\d*\.?\d+/, '').scan(/\w+|\p{P}/)
```

See [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/jMhiKp)

Comment: I also added an alternative approach that looks more readable.

Comment: I think I failed to escape the dot. I fixed it and now it will only avoid matching *dots* followed with a digit.

Comment: I have changed the accepted answer in light of your comment pointing out that akuhn's answer won't catch punctuation followed by a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
str = "We bought 3.5 million shirts."
str.scan(/[[:alpha:]]+|[[:punct:]](?![[:digit::]])/)
# => ["We", "bought", "million", "shirts", "."]
```

How does this work?

- `[[:alpha:]]+` selects one or more letters, aka words
- `[[:punct:]](?![[:digit::]])` selects punctation that is not followed by a number

Comment: Instead of the `rescue nil` hack, you could use `.grep_v(/\d+\.?\d*/)` to select non-numeric strings.

Comment: Thanks akuhn, I would like to get the punctuation as a separate entity in the resulting array ["We", "bought", "million", "shirts", "."]

Comment: Another excellent answer.  Thank akuhn I will go with this one as it's very clean and gets me the result I am looking for.

Comment: However, this excludes matching any punctuation followed with a digit, even if it is `:` or `;`, etc. Not sure it is important here though. With my approach, `(?!\.\d)[[:punct:]]`, only a dot before a digit won't get matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
a="We bought 3.5 million shirts 15 dolalr.;"
b=a.split(/\s+\d*\.?\d*\s*|([.,;])|[\s]+/)
puts b
```

[Try it here](http://ideone.com/hZRItm)

Output array:

```
We
bought
million
shirts
dolalr
.
```

Comment: Thanks Maverick_Mrt, I still need to get the "." at the end of the sentence or any other textual punctuation. This only gets the words.

Comment: Try now :) I fought hard to strip punctuations actually... just removed those :)